# Can I create a RAM disk using GPU Memory?

Tags: windows, gpu, readyboost, ramdisk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to use GPU memory as more main memory?](https://superuser.com/questions/337702/is-it-possible-to-use-gpu-memory-as-more-main-memory)

I would like to create a RAM disk/drive using the GPU's RAM/memory.

Then use [ReadyBoost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReadyBoost) on Windows to use the disk as extended memory.
Any tips?

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/34388/whats-the-best-ramdisk-for-windows for a list of RAM disks for windows.

Comment: a ramdisk stores stuff in volatile memory. the disks used for readyboost store stuff in permanent memory. do you understand the two different storage methods?

Comment: @akira Readyboost data is deleted after every restart, so there's no real difference.

Comment: @David Freitas  Do any of them actually use GPU memory? It would be counterproductive to use regular RAM for ReadyBoost.

Comment: @AndrejaKo: reference?

Comment: @akira I asked a qquestion about it [here](http://superuser.com/q/178386/36601) and in the end response was that it's impossible to keep data after restart.

Comment: @AndrejaKo: ah, ok. btw, the "ReadyBoot" part of the same document is interesting as well .. windows just uses RAM (to speed up the boot process) if there is enough of it ...

Answer (score 3):

Apparently this is possible with Linux:

> Graphics cards contain a lot of very fast RAM, typically between 64 and 512 MB. With Linux, it's possible to use it as swap space, or even as RAM disk.

[Source](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Using_Graphics_Card_Memory_as_Swap)

But I've found nothing similar for Windows.